# multiple deposits using the same address for investment

Tags: wallet

i am new to the bitcoin thin and i want to know if i can keep the same adress for send and recive some money.
I use multibit HD wallet.
Beyond the line is what the help of he investment party tells me but since i am new i do not realy understand.

---

– There is no registration — you are identified via your bitcoin address only.

– Do not use Shared coin transaction.

– You are able to make multiple deposits using the same address.

– Until your payment is confirmed in the bitcoin network (included into a block), it is not deposited and does not appears in the list of recent payments. It can take several minutes, sometimes up to one hour, to mark the transaction as confirmed.

please some help/advise.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yeah it seems like your correct, just make sure to be in control of your private key.